Wake on Lan not working even though WireShark captures it
My goal is to be able to start a Windows 11 machine with a WoL packet. I already confirmed that the packet is received with WireShark, regardless, the machine does not turn on, even if it's in sleep mode.

Motherboard: Asus Z790

I covered the steps suggested by this guide.


Does your Ethernet switch still show the port as active while the machine is asleep? 2) Does the motherboard happen to have a "Modern Standby" setting somewhere?



it doesn't. Even though it's lit up at the motherboard side and the switch side. Here's the switch, and router. Machine nic is Marvell 10Gb. Switch port is 10G SFP+. 2) Couldn't find anything like that in the manual


Right, so if the switch doesn't see the link as still being up, then it's not going to be able to deliver the WoL frame through that link, is it? In general I doubt that's going to work with an 10G SFP+ NIC, for several reasons... Is it connected via fiber, DAC, or RJ45 SFP?

@grawity through RJ45 SFP. It's weird that the switch doesn't see it as up. The status lights are on on both ends ‍♂️

@grawity oh, an update, it looks like I was looking at the wrong screen. The switch does indeed declare the port as In Use. Have a look please. You can see that when the machine is asleep, the connection drops to 1Gbps, which is a good sign based on the AI below : )

Do you call every numbered list "AI", now?

Only the ones that disregard context

Honestly, your question looks a lot more as if it was generated from "ask a question about Wake on Lan not working on Asus Z790" prompt, as it lacks any details/debugging.

Could you list out the actual steps you took enabling WoL? A link telling us what you did doesn't help so much, and we have various reasons not to trust such links. You telling us what you did to enable it, validating the settings you've set, will be better information, and will make a better question.

Are you saying that because of your trust issues you want me to copy each step from the guide over to the question?

There are quite a few obstacles for WoL to work.

Your NIC needs to support it. Some add-on NICs don't, most onboard do. A good indicator for this is that the link LED stays lit when shutting down the system. A reduced link speed (10/100 Mbit/s) is a very good sign.
Configure the mainboard BIOS to wake by PCIe power management event. Depending on the board, the setting is "Power by PME", "Wake on PCI-E" or similar.
Make sure the OS's NIC driver doesn't disable WoL on system shutdown - many do. Again, check the link LED after power down.
Most NICs only wake from soft off (ACPI S5), not from sleep/standby (ACPI S3).
Make sure the magic packet reaches its target. Most often, a local (limited) broadcast to 255.255.255.255 for UDP port 9 is used, but you can actually use any encapsulation you like, as long as the magic sequence makes it to the NIC. Packet capturing is a good tool to check whether the packet makes it.
If you need to wake/route from another subnet (via LAN or VPN), you can use a directed broadcast, e.g. 192.168.10.255 for a device on the 192.168.10.0/24 subnet. Make sure the last-hop router is configured to forward the directed broadcast and actually broadcast it. Again, packet capturing is your friend.
If broadcasting is not an option for routed WoL, use a dummy IP address on the device's subnet. The address must not be used in any other way. For the last hop router to forward it, you create a static ARP entry on it with a dummy MAC address. You can use an LAA group address (second hex digit ending in 3, 7, b, f) or actually any MAC address that doesn't exist on the network. When the address is unknown, your switches flood frames for it just like a broadcast. This dummy IP/MAC address method even works with IPv6. You only need a single dummy address on a subnet to wake any host - it's about the magic sequence, the IP address doesn't matter.
Trying to use multicast (e.g. for IPv6) from remote most often doesn't work since multicast needs special routing (PIM).
Number 7 also works from the Internet with port forwarding. Of course, anyone could use it unless you restrict the source on your firewall.
NICs with a reconfigured MAC address may be tricky. Most only use their hardware default MAC but some the software configured one. Best idea is to wake both.

Since your board features two NICs, WoL most likely only works with the 2.5G twisted-pair port. You can safely connect it to the switch but remove/disable all IP addresses and protocols from it.
